# Почему не сработал hasClass?

Tags: jquery, javascript

Пример мини-кода:

http://jsfiddle.net/4tbo301k/1/

Comment: Потому что в this валяется document?

http://jsfiddle.net/4tbo301k/2/

Comment: хм..тогда вопрос иначе. Нужно выполнить событие **hide()** по клику на любой элемент кроме **.extendWrapper** и все, что внутри него.

Comment: @Oleg Ponomarchuk, http://jsfiddle.net/4tbo301k/3/ но, боюсь, задумка с астериском изначально плохая.

Comment: Почему плохая? Может, заместо **this.nodeName** вытянуть **this.class** и сравнить его с **.extendWrapper**?

Comment: @Oleg Ponomarchuk, да работать-то точно будет, просто по-хорошему надо давать событию всплывать и ловить его на верхнем элементе, а в .extendWrapper как раз-таки останавливать.

Comment: Если сделать: **this.className** - ничего не происходит. Выводится весь DOM

Comment: @Oleg Ponomarchuk, там e.stopPropagation() не просто так висел.

http://jsfiddle.net/4tbo301k/6/

Comment: Т.е. достаточно сравнить класс  **$(e.target).attr('class')**? А если атрибут `class` имеет несколько классов? Дело в том, что в блоке **.extendWrapper** есть другие блоки, клик по которым тоже необходимо запретить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[[@Oleg Ponomarchuk](/users/18030/oleg-ponomarchuk)](/users/18030/oleg-ponomarchuk), омг. По клику вызывается событие. Вызывается на самом нижнем элементе и ползет по дереву вверх, этакая забавная виртуальная каракатица, стремящаяся к полному освобождению через всплывание до document и выше. Чтобы прибить любой элемент документа, можно повесить, как я показал, обработчик на самый верхний уровень, и через этот единый обработчик ловить все события-клики в документе. После отлова каракатицы кликнутый элемент определяется по `e.target`. Больше `e.target` нигде не нужен, вообще, он нужен только для того, чтобы словленное на верхнем уровне событие указало на тот элемент, по которому кликнули.

Чтобы избавить от такой участи `.extend-wrapper` (я специально не буду писать кэмелкейсом, потому что это плохая практика, хорошо?) и его детей, достаточно перехватить событие и не давать ему всплыть. Что и делает вызов `e.stopPropagation()`, повешенный в обработчик на `.extend-wrapper` - он приказывает событию прекратить распространяться вверх (вообще еще есть распространение вниз, но я уснул на той главе), предотвращая таким образом срабатывание обработчика клика на верхнем уровне - до него событие просто не дойдет. **Ничего определять уже не нужно**. Если событие отловилось, значит оно уже совершено на `.extend-wrapper` или одном из его дочерних элементов, просто надо остановить его.

Такая уж участь у бедной каракатицы.